# Importing and Replacing APEX application with build status "Run Application Only"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I recently had an issue where a developer "unknowingly" made direct changes to code on an APEX app in the production environment.

To prevent developers from being able to do this; I was suggested importing the app with the 'Run Application Only' Build Status.
   It sure does prevent users from making "accidental" changes to the production environment, but now we can't import and override the application with the same App ID now.
   It tells us...
   'The application could not be installed because its build status is Run Application Only. If you wish to install the application, you must first log in as a Workspace Administrator. '
   Okay, cool...but we are logged in using the workspace admin.

I guess we can change the build status back to 'Run and Build Application' when we want to import and override the application, but that seems rather excessive for just importing apps.
   What can be done here?

Thanks in advance :)
APEX v5.0.4
Oracle 11g

Comment: I've never really seen a good reason to use Build Status - I prefer to use the Run-time Only option to lock Prod down completely (deployments are only done via the command-line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still overwrite the application if you run the application export script. Export your application from your dev environment - this gives you a SQL*Plus script (e.g. `f100.sql`) that you can then run directly on the prod environment.

(tested in Oracle APEX 5.0.3)

Comment: Aha, so - you wouldn't actually "Import" the `f100.sql` via Apex, but run it as a script (e.g. at the SQL*Plus prompt). Connected as APEX_xxxxxx user, I presume?

Comment: Yes, but don't run it as APEX_xxxxxx, run it as the schema that is associated with the workspace.

Comment: I've just exported one of my applications. Comment (at the beginning of the .SQL script) says "You should run the script connected to SQL*Plus as the Oracle user
APEX_050100 or as the owner (parsing schema) of the application" so - it doesn't really matter, does it? BTW, I've never imported it via SQL*Plus, always via Apex import utility. Apparently, I didn't have to. Thank you for the info!

Comment: Ah, ok - fair enough :)

Comment: oh okay, so I run the export file with sqlplus. Is there a way to specify the APP ID when importing so I can replace the existing application?

Comment: By default f100.sql will overwrite app ID 100. You can override this by running `apex_application_install.set_application_id(119);` before running the script. More info: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2013/05/deploying-application-express-on-the-command-line/